# Adding custom bootup script to Android-x86 Nougat

Tags: android-x86, scripts, selinux, init.d

I've been happy using Android-x86 Nougat on my system. Thanks to everyone who made that work.
I'm now trying to make one small change which is that I want to run a custom `init` script (a shell script) at bootup.

It seemed like a simple idea which I've done before on KitKat without problems. I modified `init.rc` and added a service to start my script.
But what happens is on bootup, I see:

```
04-17 13:16:14.823  1210  1210 I init    : type=1400 audit(0.0:6): avc: denied { execute_no_trans } for path="/system/bin/mystart" dev="loop1" ino=280 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
```

That error is a SELinux permission error so I then proceeded to try these solutions:

1. Disabling SElinux

   ```
   write /sys/fs/selinux/enforce 0
   ```

   And checked that this causes the system to be in permissive mode but at bootup, the same error still occurs.
2. Adding a custom SELinux policy, I added:

   ```
   build/target/board/generic/sepolicy/mystart.te
   type mystart, domain;
   type mystart_exec, exec_type, file_type;

   init_daemon_domain(mystart)
   ```

   But this still doesn't allow the service to proceed.
3. Tried to run it as a post action:

   ```
   on property:dev.bootcomplete=1
   exec u:r:shell:s0 shell shell input log adb sdcard_rw sdcard_r net_bt_admin net_bt inet net_bw_stats -- /system/bin/sh /system/bin/mystart
   ```

   This still hits the same avc issue.

**Edit:** This issue is for a boot script (not an ELF executable as in the other case) and furthermore, as I mentioned above, turning off SELinux enforce does not permit the script to be run.

Answer (score 0):

The avc denial you have got states that:

> `init` is running with its context `u:r:init:0`, you want it to execute `/system/bin/mystart` (script, binary, whatever) which is labeled as `u:object_r:system_file:s0`. But `init` isn't allowed to execute `system_file` in sepolicy. However you have set SELinux permissive, so it's just a warning, not actual denial.

Therefore you don't need to do anything with SELinux unless you set it enforcing. There must be some other problem with your shell script. Put `set -x; exec >/data/media/0/mystart.log 2>&1` at the start of your script to see what happens when it's executed.

**RELATED:** [How to run an executable on boot and keep it running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526)