# How to run a script in background from adb shell?

Tags: adb, root-access, shell, scripts, usb-tethering

I have a problem with USB tethering on my rooted Nougat phone (LineageOS). After some time phone stops USB tethering. To fix that I run the following script like this:

```
adb shell
su
nohup sh tether.sh &
exit
exit
```

tether.sh

```
#!/system/bin/sh
service list
while true;
do
  if ! pidof -s dnsmasq > /dev/null
  then
    echo -n "Connectivity lost at "
    date -u +%FT%TZ
    echo "Waiting 3 seconds..."
    sleep 3
    echo "Calling ConnectivityManager.setUsbTethering(false)"
    service call connectivity 33 i32 0 2>&1
    sleep 3
    echo "Calling ConnectivityManager.setUsbTethering(true)"
    service call connectivity 33 i32 1 2>&1
    echo "Waiting 3 seconds..."
  fi
  sleep 3
done
```

Problem: If I use `nohup` my call to `service call connectivity` fails with service not found. And I put `service list` on top of the script which returns `Found 0 services:`. However the same commands work when ran directly from `adb shell; su`.

Why `service call` doesn't work inside this background script? Does it need the same `tty` to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processes receive [signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) from other processes or kernel as a warning or as a request to make some change in state. Receiving processes can *block*, *ignore* or *catch* signals, except `SIGKILL` which does what the name says. A process receives `SIGHUP` (hangup signal) when its controlling terminal (virtual or pseudo) disconnects or its controlling process (which is usually a shell) terminates. Quoted from `adb shell` [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/adb/shell_service.cpp#199):

> PTYs automatically send SIGHUP to the slave-side process when the master side of the PTY closes

<sup>* See [Terminals and Shells on Android](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-terminal-shell-display-server-t3756163) for details on PTYs</sup>

Process can then handle the signal to continue its execution or just gets killed by the kernel.

`nohup` makes a process run (usually in background) by simply ignoring `SIGHUP` even if the controlling terminal closes. Additionally if FDs `0`, `1` and `2` of the process are attached to the terminal, `nohup` redirects `STDIN` from `/dev/null` and `STDOUT`/`STDERR` to `nohup.out` file.

Android's built-in `/system/bin/nohup` has some bad implementation like many other applets of `toybox`. It replaces `STDIN` with nothing and leaves `STDERR` attached to the terminal. So all shell commandline tools which are related to `system_server` behave unexpectedly because of no FD `0`.

Solution is to use `nohup` e.g. from busybox or do:

```
nohup tether.sh </dev/null &
```

Or without `nohup`:

```
tether.sh </dev/null &>/sdcard/usb.log &
```

In order to make sure a program ignores `SIGHUP`, add `trap '' 1` to script above the program to be executed. But it's not required with Android's default MirBSD Korn Shell (`/system/bin/sh`) which doesn't send `SIGHUP` to all jobs (children processes) in the same session i.e. attached to the same terminal. So `nohup` or `trap` isn't essentially required, whether shell exits or gets killed.

Secondly `mksh` doesn't detach from terminal(s) completely because in addition to `STDIN/OUT/ERR`, it attaches to `/dev/tty` directly <sup>([ref](https://github.com/MirBSD/mksh/blob/mksh-R57/main.c#L1162))</sup>. So detaching FDs `0/1/2` doesn't suffice. However there's a daemon mode which completely detaches the command from terminal:

```
/system/bin/sh -T- tether.sh
```

Also `mksh` [unblocks all signals](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/1563#issuecomment-506616704), though not relevant here.

`bash` provides better job management; user can configure with `huponexit` whether or not to always send `SIGHUP` to all jobs on exit <sup>([ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html))</sup>. Bash's built-in `disown` command can be used to exclude jobs from receiving signals.

To keep script running in foreground, a multiplexer like `tmux` or `screen` can be used. That's what I do, particularly with `su` binaries from rooting solutions which don't detach (due to limited implementation of pseudo-terminals), when a program is running in background. See [this issue](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/1544#issuecomment-504843590) for details.

**RELATED:** [How to run an executable on boot and keep it running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526)

Comment: -T- is my new toy, didn't know about it. Simple syntax and does what I need. Very elaborate thank you.