# How to use "/etc/hosts" file as only DNS on Android?

Tags: internet, dns, hosts

On my Android-based device I need to block access to all websites except ones are in a whitelist. I know that on desktop Windows I can list allowed hosts in the hosts file and then switch the DNS in the network adapter from automatically obtained to `127.0.0.1`. And now I can access only websites from the hosts file.

I've tried the same thing by adding allowed hosts in the `system/etc/hosts` file  on Android and then I've added the line

```
new_domain_name_servers="127.0.0.1 $new_domain_name_servers"
```

to the beggining of the file `/etc/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/20-dns.conf` as described by the [link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/xda-university/guide-how-to-change-dns-android-device-t3273769).

And then I've restarted my device.

But I still can access all websites, so the solution doesn't work. And even if I just add a website to be resolved as 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file and clear browser cache, the website is still opened.

**PS:** I'm interested only in a solution which could be done on rooted device only (Android 4.0.4)

Answer (score 2):

Add allowed hosts to `/etc/hosts` and define these firewall rules to block any outgoing DNS queries on standard UDP port `53`:

```
~# iptables -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j REJECT
```

<sup>* May also use less rude `DROP` target in place of `REJECT`</sup>

To be on safe side also block TCP port:

```
~# iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j REJECT
```

`iptables` is part of stock Android releases. You need to add these rules on every boot. Use `init.d` script or define `init` service: [How to run an executable on boot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526)

Comment: Do you mean if I turn my device off and then turn on back, the blocking rules would not work?

Comment: @stckvrw `iptables` rules are not saved anywhere. You need to apply the rule(s) on every boot. Then blocking will definitely work.

Comment: Is there a way how to block all hosts except those are in the hosts permanently? For example by changing some file(s) on rooted device?

Comment: @stckvrw **Is there a way how to block all hosts except those are in the hosts permanently?** That's what the original question is and that's what I answered. **For example by changing some file(s) on rooted device?** See the link in answer. That explains how to create a file in `/etc/init` to execute some commands on every boot.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I understood you incorrectly. Do you mean if I add your rules to a file in `/etc/init` and then reboot my device, the file automatically will run the rules again without any manual actions?