# Need to add custom script as service in init.rc for Android 10

Tags: selinux, aosp

I am trying run shell script in device boot-up time.

Steps:

1. Created shell script and placed into ***/system/bin/usbmountd.sh***
2. Added test.sh in inir.rc.

   ```
   service usbmountd /system/bin/usbmountd.sh
   user system
   disabled
   oneshot
   ```
3. Add a new Domain “usbmountd.te” in the location of ***device/broadcom/XXX/sepolicy/treble/ usbmountd.te***

   ```
    type usbmountd, domain;
    type usbmountd_exec, exec_type, file_type;
    init_daemon_domain(usbmountd)
   ```
4. Add the Label "/system/bin/usbmountd.sh" to ***device/broadcom/XXX/sepolicy/treble/file_contexts***

   ```
    /system/bin/usbmountd     u:object_r: _exec:s0
   ```
5. Added in ***device/broadcom/xxx/sepolicy/xxx/file.te***

   ```
    type usbmountd_exec, system_file_type, file_type;
   ```

Error:

```
[ 81% 747/921] build out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows
FAILED: out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows
/bin/bash -c "(ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=0 out/host/linux-x86/bin/checkpolicy -M -c             30 -o out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows.tmp out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/policy.conf ) && (out/host/linux-x86/bin/sepolicy-analyze out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows.tmp neverallow -w -f out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/policy_2.conf ||           ( echo \"\" 1>&2;         echo \"sepolicy-analyze failed. This is most likely due to the use\" 1>&2;            echo \"of an expanded attribute in a neverallow assertion. Please fix\" 1>&2;           echo \"the policy.\" 1>&2;            exit 1 ) ) && (touch out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows.tmp ) && (mv out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows.tmp out/target/product/xxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_neverallows_intermediates/sepolicy_neverallows )"
device/xxx/xxx/sepolicy/treble/usbmountd.te:3:ERROR 'Duplicate declaration of type' at token ';' on line 60116:
type usbmountd_exec, exec_type, file_type;
type usbmountd, domain;
checkpolicy:  error(s) encountered while parsing configuration
```

Comment: Development questions are off-topic here but this is how it can be done from end user's perspective: [How to run an executable on boot and keep it running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213353/how-to-run-an-executable-on-boot-and-keep-it-running)

Answer (score 1):

The error is `'Duplicate declaration of type'`

The problem is step 5 in which you declare
`type usbmountd_exec, system_file_type, file_type;`

You already declared that same type `usbmountd_exec` in step 3. So remove the duplicate declaration.

Also in step 4 it should look like this:
`/system/bin/usbmountd.sh     u:object_r:usbmountd_exec:s0`