# How could I prevent some smartphone's IMEI and/or ICCID leakage through getprop output?

Tags: privacy, imei, magisk

By chance, I found some Android smartphone would leak IMEI through `getprop`, you could test in Termux like this:

```
# Tested on a Mi 5s Plus (Natrium)
$ getprop | grep imei
[persist.radio.imei]: [86REDACTED]
[persist.radio.imei1]: [REDACTED]
[persist.radio.imei2]: [REDACTED]
[ro.ril.oem.imei]: [REDACTED]
[ro.ril.oem.imei1]: [REDACTED]
[ro.ril.oem.imei2]: [REDACTED]
```

On a OnePlus 7 sold in China I even get ICCID of SIM card which could be used to track and retrive your personal data from ISP...

```
$ getprop | grep iccid
[persist.radio.bksim.iccid]: [REDACTED]
[persist.radio.ddssim.iccid]: [REDACTED]
```

And I have Magisk installed, so I come up with the idea of deleting these props using Magisk's ability to [run startup script](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/docs/guides.md). I have tried using this script below:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
# /data/adb/service.d/0001deletethefuckingimei.sh, already has execute permission

# For debugging
touch /sdcard/init

# Wait till the system boots up
while [ "$(getprop sys.boot_completed)" != "1" ]; do
  sleep 1
done

# For debugging
touch /sdcard/after-boot

/sbin/resetprop -p --delete persist.radio.imei
/sbin/resetprop -p --delete persist.radio.imei1
/sbin/resetprop -p --delete persist.radio.imei2
/sbin/resetprop -p --delete persist.radio.meid
# For 3rd party ROMs like LineageOS
/sbin/resetprop -p --delete ro.ril.oem.imei
/sbin/resetprop -p --delete ro.ril.oem.imei1
/sbin/resetprop -p --delete ro.ril.oem.imei2
/sbin/resetprop -p --delete ro.ril.oem.meid
# For MIUI
/sbin/resetprop -p --delete ro.ril.miui.imei
/sbin/resetprop -p --delete ro.ril.miui.imei1
/sbin/resetprop -p --delete ro.ril.miui.imei2
/sbin/resetprop -p --delete ro.ril.miui.meid
# For OnePlus leaking ICCID
/sbin/resetprop -p --delete persist.radio.bksim.iccid
/sbin/resetprop -p --delete persist.radio.ddssim.iccid

# For debugging
touch /sdcard/done
```

<s>But it seems that this script has never been executed, as there is no `/sdcard/init`.</s> Somehow these props are set in the middle of the booting process, having no idea how it is set.

Currently I am using [SmartPack Kernel Manager](https://github.com/SmartPack/SmartPack-Kernel-Manager/) to run script after Android boots up, and limits untrusted apps running automatically at startup.

Comment: So the question is how to run a script on startup?

Comment: @IrfanLatif Partially...Yes? Just running resetprop to delete those containing IMEI before startup. With Magisk I thought this would be easier...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run an executable on boot and keep it running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213353/how-to-run-an-executable-on-boot-and-keep-it-running)

Comment: The problem is that it is hardcoded in the firmware (Correct me if I am wrong! ) and we could do nothing about it except delete this using Magisk's ```resetprop``` utility before apps start. So this is the point running a startup script.

Comment: OK, so I edited the problem for a more general discussion - Maybe someone else could figure all the mess out.

Comment: you probably run magisk in core only mode and script is not executed at all