# Android execute script at logout

Tags: shell, bash, python

I would like to execute a script at logout with my GS7 android 9 (Resurrection Remix). I see that it is advised to use tasker. I guess it is possible to do that without installing a graphical application.
I connect to the smartphone through adb and have a shell. Where can I write a file in the file system with bash or python commands that will be executed at logout ? Also, how should I manage the bash or python environment in order to have it working ?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

On a rooted device you can make use of `init`'s [`on shutdown`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r1/rootdir/init.rc#819) trigger:

```
# /etc/init/custom.rc

on shutdown
    exec - -- /path/to/executable
```

For more details on how to run an executable from `init`'s `.rc` file, and what factors need to be taken care of, see my answer to [How to run an executable on boot and keep it running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213353)

Comment: I tried the solution and was able to do things. I created a `shutdown.sh` script, make it executable and put it under `/bin/`
```
#!/bin/bash

/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/mosquitto_pub MOSQUITTO_COMMAND
```

And it works from adb shell.

Then I created the `/etc/init/custom.rc` file with
```
on shutdown
       exec - -- /system/bin/shutdown.sh
```
And when I shut it down that doesn't work. I think the files permissions are good. However, I am confused with the android file system. Should I make everything under `/system` or not ?

Comment: How to make code blocks in comments ?

Comment: I tried different things about custom.rc. Can not get it doing anything at shutdown. I don't find anything online. Any suggestion ?

Comment: @yoarch the usual troubleshooting steps. Set proper mode, owner, context on files. Apply `dos2unix` if needed. Start with something simple like `exec - -- /bin/echo Hello`. Then replace `-` with `u:r:magisk:s0` or some other super context. Or set SELinux permissive. Check `dmesg` for `init` log.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Could you give me a concrete example with /bin/echo Hello please ? As the partition seems to be read only, I can not do something like exec - -- /bin/echo Hello > /some/file.
I checked the dmesg logs with dmesg | grep init. But I don't see anything related to the custom.rc script.
The path should be "/bin/echo Hello" or "/system/bin/echo Hello" ?
I guess I need magisk to be installed in order to use the u:r:magisk:s0 context ? That is my case.

Comment: Any one ?
I can not get that script be run while shutting down my android phone. This is the only part I can not get working ..