# How to repack Magisk boot image? (Magisk installed)

Tags: root-access, boot, magisk, services

everyone.

I have a OnePlus 5t, updated to Android 9 and Project Treble.

I have my own Magisk module for my own tweaks, but I am not satisfied. I found that I need a patched init.rc in order to have one script of mine run when I need it.

There is an official howto chapter dedicated to an "overlay.d" directory that can modify files on the root of the filesystem, say `/init.rc`, `https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/guides.html#root-directory-overlay-system` , however, this "howto" is terse and hard to understand for people not familiar with Magisk's internals.

There is also a script that should help to repack the boot image `https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/scripts/boot_patch.sh` , but it is relying on certain commands not in that directory.

By trial and error I have found a way to extract "`magiskboot`" from the magisk's install `Magisk-*.zip`, and I also found that this magiskboot can unpack the `/dev/disk/by-name/boot` partition. (I know, that is probably insane, a partition is not a file, but somehow magiskboot manages to navigate it by itself.) But that requires running that command on the phone itself (with magisk's su), and I am not sure how valid this is. Trying to run the "`boot_patch.sh`" by first copying it to the phone, and using the extracted rootfs.cpio seems way beyond my ability, and I am also very unsure whether this can be done with the system booted, or I should do it from TWRP, or whatever.

So, a decent guide (for dummies) on how to patch the boot image would be appreciated. I only need to add two files: `custom.rc`, with the service description, and a `custom.sh` with the service code itself.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run an executable on boot and keep it running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213353/how-to-run-an-executable-on-boot-and-keep-it-running)

Comment: Note magisk doesn't actually modify files on filesystem, that's why it's called overlay ;) https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2073775

Comment: @alecxs no, unfortunately not. I had followed that guide, before asking this question, and I have my "service.sh" in /bin/, and service.rc in /etc/init/ , but the service is not getting registered with the android init, and `setprop svc.start custom" does not trigger it. Overlaying is totally fine, I don't really care how exactly my services get into the system, as long as it does not trigger dm-verity and cts.

Comment: so "for dummies" downgrade cpio 2.12, run unpackimg.sh, create overlay.d directory, copy-paste custom.rc example code and place file in overlay.d, name your script myscript.sh and place in sbin, run repackimg.sh and fastboot boot image-new.img