# Where should I put Android kernel modules?

Tags: kernel, android-13

I compiled custom kernel with couple extra drivers and due they had conflicts when I tried to add them as built-in drivers to kernel, I had to compile them as separate modules. I signed the modules, insmodded them and they work well. No conflicts.
The problem is that I neither have `modules` directory in `/system/lib` folder nor `/vendor/lib`. I tried to create them manually but even after creation, it didn't load after reboot.
Now questions:

1. Where can I put kernel modules if I don't have these folders?
2. How can I make it without modifying system? I want to ship the kernel as only 1 AnyKernel3 zip.

Please, if you at least know answer to one of these questions, respond either as answer or comment.

Comment: I feel that this is about programming/development, so off-topic here.

Comment: Put them in `/system/lib/modules/` or `/vendor/lib/modules/`. You need to load them using a boot script. They are not auto-loaded. To avoid modifying `/system`, use [Magisk modules](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/guides.html#the-system-folder).

Comment: @IrfanLatif, I can remount /vendor partition as rw and then add those modules and folders. Issue is at loading them. How can I load them?

Comment: My init binary is compiled code. Where else can I add `insmod /vendor/lib/modules/module.ko` line?

Comment: See [Magisk Boot Scripts](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/guides.html#boot-scripts) and [How to run an executable on boot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526).

Comment: Thanks @IrfanLatif . I will take a look at them